Angular not injecting service
I have a weird issue with my component where it doesn't seem to be injecting the service.
processService = inject(ProcessService);
accessService = inject(AccessService);

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.processService.getData().pipe(takeUntil(destroy$)).subscribe(this.processData);
}

processData(data: ReviewObject) {
    if(data)
        this.accessService.getSup(data.id).pipe(takeUntil(destroy$)).subscribe(console.log);
    else {
        //omitted code
    }
}

it basically throws error that getSup is undefined, it seems like its not injecting the accessService, which is weird.
What am i doing wrong?

please share the service details decorator and some code related to the issue

Try calling processData in an arrow function like this:
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.processService.getData().pipe(takeUntil(destroy$)).subscribe(data => this.processData(data));
}

If you are passing the function directly, the context of this in your processData function will refer to the observable, not the component in which you defined the function. To avoid this you have to either use arrow functions or use Function.bind to specify the context.
More about this here: Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?

Ahh man, i knew it was something stupid, perils of 2am work.
